# Image magic rotate particular page in php

Tags: php, image, pdf, imagemagick

I have a PDF where I need to rotate particular page in PDF.
I have used below command but it rotates all pages in that pdf

```
convert -density 300x300 -rotate 90 input.pdf  result.pdf
```

Is there any way to rotate particular page ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using ImageMagick, you *can* rotate a particular page using the `[pagenum]` syntax after the filename like this:

```
convert document.pdf[3] -rotate 90 page3rotated.pdf
```

However, that will only extract that single page (i.e. page 3), rotate it and save it (and it alone) in the output file. Of course, you *could* extract ALL the pages, rotate the one you want and re-assemble your PDF, but I can't help thinking that there must be a better way with a different tool.

In general, you should be aware that ImageMagick will rasterise your PDF (so it is basically a picture) and that words/text will no longer be selectable as words/text when ImageMagick puts your PDF back together.

Comment: But this solution will take more time if there is n number of pages

Comment: I agree - ImageMagick is probably not the correct tool, but I don't know a better way - maybe somebody else will. At least this will work, and it does answer what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux, You may use PDFMod. This allows independent operations on given pages of the pdf file.

I have attached a screenshot below for demonstration purpose.

[image]